# MySQL - How to group sum top 6 and the rest

Tags: mysql

I have reports table that aggregates data each product quantity each day.

```
    SELECT r.year, r.month, c.id, c.client_name, p.product_name, cc.country_name, sum(r.quantity) units FROM
    client c
    join report r on c.id = r.client_id
    join product p on r.product_id = p.id
    join country cc on r.country_id = c.id
    WHERE r.year = year(now())
    group by r.year, r.month, c.id, p.product_name, cc.country_name
```

I'm trying to figure out how group units sum by month, client, product and country where query shows sum  for top 5 countries and rest is sum from bottom countries. Something like this:

```
    case
    when sum(r.quantity) = 'Top 1' then cc.country_name
    when sum(r.quantity) =  Top 2' then cc.country_name
    .....
    when sum(r.quantity) = 'Top 2' then cc.country_name
    else 'Other'
```

How can I do this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. Here i sort the result from most quantity to less and add a row number. so the first 6 are the top.

please try it, but i cant tested.

```
SELECT
    @nr := ( @nr +1) AS nr,
    IF ( @nr < 7, CONCAT('Top ',@nr), 'other' ) AS top, 
    r.* FROM (
    SELECT r.year, r.month, c.id, c.client_name, p.product_name, cc.country_name, sum(r.quantity) units 
    FROM CLIENT c
    JOIN report r ON c.id = r.client_id
    JOIN product p ON r.product_id = p.id
    JOIN country cc ON r.country_id = c.id
    WHERE r.year = YEAR(now())
    GROUP BY r.year, r.month, c.id, p.product_name, cc.country_name
    ORDER BY sum(r.quantity) DESC
) AS r
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0 ) AS params;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Query returns "#1054 - Unknown column 'nr' in 'field list'"

Comment: daba - ups, i have 2 typos in one line :-( IF ( @nr < 7, CONCAT('Top ',@nr), 'other' ) AS top,  . i have correct it in my answer